# pyenv, virtualenv, autoenv can not recognize python

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I'm using `pyenv, virtualenv, autoenv`.
When I activated pyenv, it shows an error.

```
Chois@Chois-MacPro ~ $pyenv activate chacha_dabang
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior.
(chacha_dabang) Chois@Chois-MacPro ~ $python
pyenv: python3.5: command not found

The `python3.5' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.5.1
```

So, I checked with `which`:

```
(chacha_dabang) Chois@Chois-MacPro ~ $which python
/Users/Chois/.pyenv/shims/python
```

I execute python with this one :

```
(chacha_dabang) Chois@Chois-MacPro ~ $/Users/Chois/.pyenv/shims/python
Python 3.5.1 (default, Aug  3 2016, 11:09:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

It works well!!!

I don't know why it doesn't work when I type just `python`

Need your help.

Here is my `PATH` :

```
Chois@Chois-MacPro ~ $echo $PATH
/Usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/20160716/shims:/Users/Chois/.pyenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/Chois/Library:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Chois/phantomjs-1.9.2-macosx/bin
```

and `.pyenv`:

```
Chois@Chois-MacPro versions $pwd
/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions
Chois@Chois-MacPro versions $ls
3.5.1         chacha_dabang
```

Comment: It is not failing to execute `python`. It is failing to execute `python3.5`. Do a `which` on that and, if it doesn't exist, create a symlink. I have no idea why this wasn't done correctly by your install process.

Comment: I have the same problem. @Two-BitAlchemist - so the installation should have created symlinks? I can certainly do that. Perhaps that will allow pyenv to update my PAT, because my PATH doesn't have any pyenv stuff in it after running `pyenv local 3.5.0`. is that what's supposed to happen? This is my first time trying to run tox so I can test with different versions of python.